# How do I auto-hide taskbar in Windows 10 without activation?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, gui

My Windows 10 is **not** activated. That is why *I cannot auto-hide a taskbar* :-( It is annoying because it covers the space I need and distracts my attention. Please, **help me auto-hide the taskbar without activating my Windows.** Do not suggest buying anything, please.

---

P.S. Windows 10x64 Pro, version 1703 (Build 15063.332).

[image]

Comment: "My Windows 10 is not activated" you should activate it then.

Comment: Yes, I had to activate it, because even with that registry hack, the watermark would return again and again. However, in regard to the original question, your answer was not relevant, because I asked about how to do that thing without activation.

Comment: I'm using Windows Sandbox and since the sanboox itself is not activated by design, this is really helpfull.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to Start-- Type Regedit--Right click Run as Administrator

Go To Given Path

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects3
```

**Before You do Changes in RegEdit. Take Backup of Registry. File -- Export**

You will Find Settings -- Right Click Modify the Binary Data.

**By Default Second Line will have below value**

[image]

**Replace it with 03 from 02. Refer below image**

[image]

Click OK and Close Registry Editor

**After Control + Alt + Del -- Task Manager -- Restart Explorer.**

Comment: Wow, it works! 
It's been almost 2 days since I applied your solution, and the taskbar auto-hides as I asked. Thank you for the advice! 
I will give you all possible thumbs up. 
PS What's more, the taskbar got a bit transparent which I also like.

Comment: Transparent look is good to look. If you activate you get good features unlocked in personalization of windows 10

Comment: that's true, but I do not have the money.

Comment: No Comments on this

Comment: have a good day and enjoy money :-)

Comment: I had to find this solution after re-installing my Windows. Thank you again, Techie Gossip :-)

Comment: @Sergey Larin Welcome

Comment: Anyway, I had to activate, because the watermark always came back. Is there a way to make this permanent?

Comment: in my case, it was already `03`, so I changed it to `02` and follow all of your steps, and its done, thx @TechieGossip, upvoted for saving my day.

Comment: still works in july 2022

Answer (score 0):

Go here. (If key `Explorer` doesn't exist, create it):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

Create DWORD value `NoTaskGrouping`(If not exist already)

```
NoTaskGrouping DWORD
```

If you don't want task buttons grouping, make it's value `1` and then restart Explorer

Comment: excuse me, but is your answer about 1) how to auto-hide the Taskbar? 2) how not to group program thumbnails together in Taskbar.
I have followed your advise and created a 64 bit registry entry in both places you mentioned, and restarted the PC, but the taskbar is not doing what I want - i want the Taskbar to slide away when my mouse is not hovering above it.